# How to derive an exact 10Hz clock from the generated clock?

Tags: verilog, clock, system-verilog, clock-speed

How do I go about getting an exact (or as close as possible) 10Hz clock from the generated clock? The master is 100MHz. I have used this 32-bit register to make a clock as close as possible to 10kHz which is done by toggling the output when bit 13 is set. LED is my generated clk which of course is just contantly on at that rate, but I plan on changing the output LED to the 10Hz clock, and verifying on an o-scope. [image]

```
module Clock_Divider(
input clk,
output reg LED
    );
 
reg [31:0]big_reg = 32'h0000_0000;
    always @ (posedge clk)
        begin
            if (big_reg[13] == 1'b1)
                begin big_reg <= 32'h0000_0000;
                    LED <= ~LED;
                end
            else
                big_reg <= big_reg + 1'b1;
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: If you know how to generate a 10 kHz clock from a 100 MHz clock, you know how to generate a 10 Hz clock from a 10 kHz clock.

Comment: You could use the DDS concept if you need fine-grain resolution. You would use a 32 bit accumulator, and a 32 bit tuning register. Every clock, accumulator = accumulator + tuning_register. The output is accumulator[31]. By changing tuning register you change the frequency.

Comment: For a precise clock, I used to start from a cheapy hardware crystal osc module, say 24M, 2M, 1M, 32.768kHz, and use also cheapy binary/decimal sync/async counter to counter to 100/10/1/0.1Hz. Of course you can then count up when you have 1.000Hz clock.

Comment: _"I have used this 32-bit register to make a clock **as close as possible** to 10kHz which is done by toggling the output when bit 13 is set."_ - Exactly what frequency did you get with this method?

Comment: @BruceAbbott 12.207kHz. From 1MHz/2^13.

Comment: 100MHz can be converted to **exactly** 10kHz by simply counting to 5000 and toggling a flip-flop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way: count to 5 million and then toggle a flip flop.  If timing is an issue in your part, you can pre-divide down to a lower frequency first (divide by 4, for example), then count to 1.25 million in your secondary counter.

```
reg [22:0] main_counter;
reg        clock_10hz;

wire       toggle;

assign  toggle = (main_counter == 23'd4_999_999);  // 5e6 including 0.

initial begin
   main_counter = 0;
   clock_10hz   = 0;
end

always @(posedge clock_100m)
    if (toggle) begin
         main_counter <= 0;
         clock_10hz   <= !clock_10hz;
    end
    else begin
         main_counter <= main_counter + 1;
    end
```

Update: edited counter to 5 million (was 50 million).  OP asking for 10Hz, not 1Hz.

Answer (score 0):

some suggestions:

1. compare with a constant.
2. load with a constant then count down.
3. load with (max value - constant) then test for overflow/or bit being set
4. DDS - add a constant, test for overflow/or bit being set

If you're short on logic resources, I can understand just testing a bit is the more efficient, but obviously it works best if your constant is a power of two.